# Copying multiple files to a Winscp directory via Script

Tags: file, scripting, copy, winscp

I have a problem when trying to upload multiple files to one WinSCP directory, i can manage to copy just one single file, but the problem is that i need to upload many files that are generated by a software, the names are not fixed ones, so i need to make use of wildcards in roder to copy all of them, i have tried many variants on the code, but it all was unsuccessful, the code i am using is:

open "sftp://myserver:MyPass@sfts.us.myserver.com" -hostkey="hostkey"

put "C:\from*.*" "/Myserverfolder/Subfolder/"

exit

This code does actually copy the first alphabetically named file, but it ignores the rest of the files.

Any help with it would be much appreciated

Comment: What is `from`? File or directory? Can you include a relevant part of a session log file?

Answer (score -1):

Try this in script

```
Lcd C:\from
Cd Myserverfolder/Subfolder
Put *
```

Try and do all manually first so you can see what's going on.